# Error when trying to install second flutter app on the emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I created a simple flutter app and run it on android emulator. It worked Ok. Now I created another one and when I'm trying to run it on the emulator I'm getting:

```
 Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
adb: failed to install /Users/Admin/Development/flutter/flutter_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
```

Once I delete the first app from emulator I'm able to install the second one and run it successfully.

So anytime I have one flutter app installed on the emulator installing another one will lead to the same error.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation? Or this is a bug?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You probably configures storage too small and you get this error when the emulator runs out of storage when you install.

Either modify the emulator configuration or uninstall before you install another app.

Open the Android Virtual Device (AVD) manager in Android Studio, edit the emulator and increase "Internal Storage" and restart the emulator.

Comment: I have 2048MB of internal storage for the emulator. Is it not enough for more than one flutter app?

Comment: It should be, but that depends on your app. In debug mode apps easily take 10x the nor,al size.

Comment: Apps are as simple as default counter app. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You can run `flutter build apk` and check the `build` directory for `debug` build output and check the size. It's probably about 70M gor a simple app. So if you have 2G and big parts free then you should be able to install a few. Hard to tell from here what exactly is going on on your system.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer For me, the apk size is 15MB while the emulator's internal storage size is 10GB. That's weird...
I had to uninstall another app on the emulator and now I can install my Flutter app.

Comment: Perfect answer.  The most important part is to restart the emulator or it will still have the same amount of storage as before.

Answer (score 40):

On android studio

1. Tools > AVD Manager
2. Edit the virtual device
3. Show advanced settings
4. Increase internal storage

[internal storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWros.png)

Comment: Highly effective, concise answer. Readers might note that (at least on Mac), one has to scroll, somewhat un-intuitively, to find the "Internal Storage".

Comment: It worked like charm! I am using Mac.

Comment: Note, 04/03/2022, it's not called AVD Manager, now it is Device Manager

Comment: Note: Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1 on macOS, I don't see an option for internal storage in "Show Advanced Settings". Any clues?

Answer (score 20):

## Free-up the space

free space used by emulators / virtual devices

1. Open `Android Studio`
2. `Tools` > `AVD Manager`
3. click `menu` icon on right side of emulator / virtual device
4. select `Wipe Data`
5. select `Yes`

There you'll see the space will be free up.

For clarity see the below image, 3+ GB space is freed to 1.0 GB.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer. I have added 10GB and it wasn't enough either. Then I wiped data and that will able to remove 5-6 GB junk data from the emulator

Answer (score 6):

## Check Free Space on Emulator - adb shell

*Your Android Emulator must be running for this to work.*

Open a Windows Command Prompt / Mac Terminal.

Go to the directory of the `adb.exe` program. (Not necessary if you have this in your PATH.)

On Windows (example location):

`cd c:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\`

If you only have one running emulator, you don't need to specify which to **connect via adb shell**, so just run:

`adb shell`

If you have **multiple emulators**, you can specify **which one** after finding the name using

`adb devices` shows running emulators

[image]

**Connect** to the emulator

`adb -s emulator-5554 shell`

You'll be presented with a **shell prompt** inside emulator:

[image]

You'll have limited permissions, so **switch user to root** with command:

`su`

Use the **disk filesystem command** to see disk usage & available space

`df`

[image]

***If you're running out of space, the Use% on `/data` will be high.  You need to free up space on `/data`***

Free up space by deleting apps you've installed...

## Delete Apps in adb shell

Your apps are found in `/data/data`:

`cd /data/data`

It's easier to see your apps by reversing the directory listing sort order so your apps will show at bottom:

`ls -ltr`

[image]

You can delete your app directly here using `rm -r`. In the above example the app is stored under `com.mobdev.user_interface_intro`:

`rm -r /data/data/com.mobdev.user_interface_intro`

Repeat for any other apps you want to delete from the emulator to free up space.

## Delete App in Emulator

You can also delete the app within the running emulator itself.  Click on the Square button > Android Settings (Gear Icon)

[image: Square button > Gear Icon]

Click on **Apps & Notifications**

[image]

Find and click on your app

[image]

Click on **Uninstall**

[image]

Repeat as necessary for other apps you want to uninstall to free up emulator space.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)
3. Open emulator
4. Try to run app

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio ==> Select your virtual device ==> Wipe Data
It helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after running the emulator multiple times on multiple projects. I deleted a 'qcow2' file and now the emulator runs peftectly so far at least.

C:\Users\admin \ .android\avd\test_avd_29.avd\userdata-qemu.img.qcow2

when I opened the file I saw that this file was like 1 milion KBytes and it seemed strange to me so I deleted it to see if this will fix the problem and it did.

Answer (score 0):

i run into this problem already several times. What I usually do, I open the terminal and first run `flutter clean` to clean all unnecessary stuff (build, dart_tool, etc.) and afterwards I run a `flutter pub get` to get the all the dependencies back in.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted some apps from the emulator and it didn't work.

But then I restarted the emulator and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

For me it did not work to edit the emulator and increase "Internal Storage" and restart the emulator.

**This is what worked for me:**

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Delete your current Android device (I deleted all my devices)
3. Add a new device (I added one with 32Gb internal storage)