# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE when attempting to run in emulator in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I keep getting this error when trying to run a simple flutter app in emulator.

[image]

Below is what is have tries

1. I have tried increasing internal storage

[image]

2. flutter clean and flutter pub get

Below is the main.dart file

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to increase the storage of emulator. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora) answer

Comment: Please refer this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010649/error-when-trying-to-install-second-flutter-app-on-the-emulator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when trying to install second flutter app on the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010649/error-when-trying-to-install-second-flutter-app-on-the-emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by going into avd and adding a new device or edit the current.

Select Hardware-> Select System image -> verify Configuration section
Click on Advance settings and increase the limit of device internal storage. It will be 800 by default.

See the images below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall some other apps from your device or wipe data of the emulator will help to install the new app

Answer (score 0):

You have increased the internal storage, but are you sure that there is space on your computer's disk? If there isn't, freeing up space would probably fix the problem